# How do I vectorise a function?

Tags: r, vectorization

How do I vectorize this function?

```
difftime2string <- function (x) {
  if (abs(x) < 1) return(sprintf("%.2fms",x*1000))
  if (abs(x) < 100) return(sprintf("%.2fsec",x))
  if (abs(x) < 6000) return(sprintf("%.2fmin",x/60))
  if (abs(x) < 108000) return(sprintf("%.2fhrs",x/3600))
  if (abs(x) < 400*24*3600) return(sprintf("%.2fdays",x/(24*3600)))
  sprintf("%.2fyears",x/(365.25*24*3600))
}
```

EDIT: I mean without [`Vectorize`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html) - how do I write vectorised code with many `if`s.

Comment: `v <- Vectorize(difftime2string)`?

Comment: Another DateTime WTF.  You do know that there aren't 365( or 365.25) days in a year?  While Josh provided an exact answer for your question, I'd strongly recommend returning the full DateTime string and then filtering on things like (pseudofunction) `if(yearpart(string)!=0)  {print using "years"}`  and so on.

Comment: P.S.  How about using `switch` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Although switch is an alternative it isn't vectorized so it doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: I was not the downvoter.

Comment: FWIW, the downvote seemed to come in right after you (apparently in response to Dason's answer) edited the question to clarify that you wanted an answer that didn't use `Vectorize`, but before I put up an alternative answer. I can *sort of* see the reasoning behind such a downvote -- questions that present a moving target can be frustrating for folks to answer -- though I tend not to cast them for something like what you did.

Comment: I did upvote both answers. I agree that moving targets are frustrating (and I have been frustrated by then as an answerer myself!) but I am afraid they are sometimes inevitable (asking a good question on the first attempt is, IMO, harder than giving a good answer on the first attempt).

Comment: @sds -- Couldn't agree more about asking a good question being the harder task. I hope you understand I wasn't saying you should've got a downvote. I was instead just speculating (perhaps wildly but I suspect not, since yours was in every other respect an examplary question) as to the answer to your question in comments ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
difftime2string <- function(x) {
    breaks <- c(0, 1, 100, 6000, 108000, 400*24*3600, Inf)
    units <- c("ms", "sec", "min", "hrs", "days", "years")
    fact <- c(1000, 1, 1/60, 1/3600, 1/(24*3600), 1/(365.25*24*3600))
    ii <- findInterval(x, breaks)
    sprintf(paste0("%.2f", units[ii]), x*fact[ii])
}

x <- c(.1, 2, 200, 6001, 109000, 500*24*3600)
difftime2string(x)
# [1] "100.00ms"  "2.00sec"   "3.33min"   "1.67hrs"   "1.26days"  "1.37years"
```

Comment: As long as we're using sprintf why not: `sprintf("%.2f%s", x*fact[ii], units[ii])`

Comment: Using `cut(x, breaks, labels = units, right = FALSE)` avoids the subsetting at the end.

Comment: @Roland: that's true, but `cut` is going to be a lot slower than `findInterval`... so it might not be worth it from a performance standpoint.

Comment: Inf appears to not be necessary. Right? Are the vectors allocated on each call?

Comment: @sds -- Right you are. Nice catch.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to do something like this with zero thought is to just use `Vectorize`

```
difftime2stringVect <- Vectorize(difftime2string)
```